# Instantiate Local Variable By Value?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, byref, byval

I sort of understand why this is happening, but not entirely. I have a base class with a `Shared` (`Static`) variable, declared like so:

```
Public Shared myVar As New MyObject(arg1, arg2)
```

In a method of a derived class, I set a local variable like so:

```
Dim myLocalVar As MyObject = myVar
```

Now when I do something like `myLocalVar.Property1 += value`, the value in `Property1` persists to the next call of that method! I suppose I get *why* it would be happening; `myVar` is being set by reference instead of by value, but I've never encountered anything like this before. Is there any way (other than my workaround which is to just create a new object using the property values of `myVar`) to create `myLocalVar` **by value**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you create `myLocalVar` you are creating a new reference to the same shared object.  If you truly want a local copy of the shared instance you will need to create a true copy.

This is done by either cloning the instance or with a copy constructor on the type that allows you to create a copy of the instance.  This is not as simple as it sounds, however, due to the differences between deep and shallow copying and a cloned or copied instance could create similar problems for you if the property you are accessing is simply a shallow-copied reference to the same instance that the property on the original instance is referencing.

The best thing I to do in this case is to create a local copy of only the parts of the shared instance that you need, rather than copying the entire object graph.  This means create a local copy of whatever type `Property1` is and using that.

Comment: yeah, this was my workaround, actually. What is the difference between "deep" and "shallow" copying? Thanks for this very knowledgeable answer!

Comment: A shallow copy means to copy just the object's "top level" properties. A deep copy would mean to copy both the top level properties and to dig into the sub-properties of the properties, etc.

Comment: @Jason: Brad Abrams has a good explanation here: http://blogs.msdn.com/brada/archive/2003/04/09/49935.aspx "Deep-copy copies the cloned object and all objects referenced by the object, recursively until all objects in the graph are copied. A non-deep copy (referred to as ‘shallow’ if only the top level references are copied) may do none, or part of a deep copy."